# Correct usage/location of tmpfs for a service in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, services, tmpfs

I wrote simple SystemD service for Raspberry Pi, which collects some data and writes it temporarily to

```
/run/user/1000
```

It worked, but on reboot I found, that this directory doesn't exist until user login.

What if I still want to use `tmpfs` for my service. Should I force creation of this directory somehow? How? Should I use another location? Which? Should I create one? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a service, create another user to run it.
Then use `/dev/shm`, or `/tmp`, for temporary storage.